# Depletion NMOS that's saturated at 0V

Tags: mosfet, nmos, saturation

May seem like a weird request for a part, but are there any Depletion NMOS out there that is already saturated when you apply 0V to gate or if the gate is not connected?

Comment: Isn't that the "definition" of depletion mode?  (Or do you have to drive the gate higher on some?)  Digikey lists several depletion mode fets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infineon make them. See [this](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/power-mosfet/n-channel-depletion-60v-600v/BSP129/productType.html?productType=db3a30443f519f93013f5c91d50e1354) for example but I wouldn't consider it sensible to leave the gate open on any mosfet. Infineon also make others so take a look at what they offer and use google to search. It won't bite you.

You might also consider the humble N channel JFET. With 0V on the gate relative to the source it conducts and can be fully turned off (<1uA) with a negative voltage applied to the gate. You might find it easier to match one of these to your requirements. There are also P channel versions.

Comment: P channel version? Do you mean a Depletion PMOS? I thought nobody manufactures them as it is a real technical challenge to dope polysilicon channel with holes?

Comment: P channel JFETs

Comment: The BSP129 which you mentioned in the link, that just won't do... The resistance is too high (6 ohms) and the current handling is too low (350mA). I need a saturated Depletion NMOS so I can quickly reset a particularly large capacitor when power is cut-off.

Comment: ^ ohh... JFETs...

Comment: Your original question asked for a source of depletion FETs. You did not mention any spec or requirements for said device. If it doesn't meet your "recently revealed" requirements then get searching and good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. Thanks for the help, though.